# Binding net.pipe to Default Web Site via IIS

Tags: iis, binding, appfabric, net.pipe

When I attempt to set up appfabric to link up to my application and monitor and track and tract it,  I get an error stating

“Workflow persistence is not functional because the net.pipe binding is not enabled for this web site.”

Now according to [This Website](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/appfabric-configuration-issues-net-4-net-pipe-and-role-services.aspx) I need to enable the net.pipe bindings for a site.  It says that To enable the net.pipe binding for a site, right-click the site in the Connections pane of IIS Manager, click Edit Bindings, and add net.pipe with binding information of “*”.

I go to Default Web Site, right click and click edit bindings,  but am unsure how binding information plays into it.  I see site bindings, one of them http no host name, port 80, ipaddress of * and no binding information.  When I click add I can put in a host name, put in a port, select an ip address, and select a type (http or https).  Where would I edit the binding information to make it * and thus no longer show the error with appfabric.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In fact, it's depending on IIS and/or Windows Server version.

As a prerequisite, you have to enable Net Pipe Activation first. You can add it via windows feature or Server manager.

[image: net pipe activation]

Here is the illustrated explanation :

First, Go to the Advanced settings on your Web Site.
Under IIS manager, it's on the right after you select your WebSite.

[image: advanced settings]

In *Enabled Protocols*, add **net.pipe** (default is http)

[image: enable protocols]

At the end, Add a new Bidning (Right Pane when you select your web site), and add a net.pipe binding with a wildcard "*" for Bidning Informaiton.

[image: net.pipe binding]

That's all.

Answer (score 7):

Cybermaxs basically has the correct answer, with one minor caveat in my experience: You might need to do an **iisreset** before things will work (that is, click <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and enter `iisreset`, or just run `iisreset` in a command line window).

As a bonus, what follows is the equivalent of what Cybermaxs included, only from Windows 8. Search for "Turn windows features on or off" to open this window:

[image]