# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a Wcf Service project. `system.serviceModel` tag in my web.config is :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="RCISPNetTcpBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign">
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="RCISP.WcfServiceBehaviour" name="RCISP.WcfService.PersonWcfService">
        <endpoint address="PersonServices" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RCISPNetTcpBinding"
          contract="RCISP.Common.ServiceContract.IPersonService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:40003/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RCISP.WcfServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have a runtime error when I want create self-hosting for service.

```
    public class ServiceFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
       protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
       {
          if (!IsInitialised) InitialiseService();
             return base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
       }

    }
```

Message of Exception is :

`Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].`

Why?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793119/could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-net-tcp

Comment: @wise_guybg: I read that question but my problem not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You said you were self hosting the service (within your own process) but based on the code above I think you're trying to host it inside of a web application. If so Visual Studio's web server can not host a net.tcp end point. You'll need to set the project up to run under IIS. Please follow the instructions [here](http://www.42spikes.com/post/Using-Silverlight-4-and-NetTCP-Duplex-Callbacks.aspx) .

If you are truly self hosting than you can leave the configuration exactly how you have it and spin up the service using the following code:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a protocol mapping to your configuration file to tell it what the "net.tcp" protocol is. Right after your `<bindings>` section add this:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="net.tcp" binding="netTcpbinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```