# WCF error "Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding"

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-server-2012-r2, net.tcp

I'm trying to run a webservice on a Windows Server 2012 R2, but I get the following error

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

**The solutions I have tried so far :**

- [Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793119/could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-net-tcp) (the first two answers)

**My web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" >
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ServerName" behaviorConfiguration="ServerInternet" >
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
            contract="Namespace.Interface"
            bindingNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/webservices"
        />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/WebService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServerInternet">
          <!-- certificate infos here -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**The advanced settings** :

[image: Advanced settings, net.tcp is enabled]

**The functionalities** I have installed on the server :

[image: Functionalities]

**Pool settings** :

- Classic pipeline
- CLR .NET 4.0
- LocalService Identity

**The site bindings**

[image]

What could be the reasons of this error?

Comment: @jstreet I added a screencapture, I have `net.tcp`, `net.pipe` and `http` on port 8080

Comment: @jstreet I changed it to `808:*`, restarted the server, but I still get the same error

Comment: @jstreet Thanks, I'll try it tomorrow, I'll keep you informed

Comment: You don't seem to have TCP Activation and TCP Port Sharing enabled in server manager, which doesn't add up, as this is required for net.tcp in IIS...

Comment: Thanks @tomasr, that was the problem, could you post your comment as an answer? (to be able to mark this post as solved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would be that you don't have TCP Activation and TCP Port Sharing enabled in server manager, which doesn't add up, as this is required for net.tcp in IIS.