# IIS hosted WCF using net.tcp

Tags: asp.net, wcf, tcp

A version of this question has been asked many times. I cannot find a solution to my particular problem.

IIS 7.5 is hosting a web app as well as a WCF service using tcp. I have this running fine on several development boxes running Windows 7.

I get the error "**Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding...**" when I try running this on a Windows Server 2008 R2. --Even when trying to access it locally, from the same box.

- I've enabled the proper bindings (net.tcp)
- I've enabled the proper windows features (non-http activation, etc.)
- the appropriate Windows services are running (net.tcp listener adapter, etc.)

Anyone have any ideas what else might be the problem?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793119/could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-net-tcp

Comment: @reckface yes, i have seen that. i don't believe the solution there is relevant to my issue.

Comment: What does your service model element in your app.config look like? Do you definitely have WAS configured on this 2008 R2 box?

Comment: My service model config is pretty straight forward--and the key point is that it runs fine on other machines. All the bullet points I mentioned in the post apply to the problem machine. Bindings are set, WAS is configured, services are running.